# Sending local storage photo into Telegram with VBA

Tags: vba, telegram-bot

Recently i am doing project where i need to get images from my local storage and send to telegram using Microsoft Excel VBA.

I cant find any solution to this matter, however i can send text message to telegram using VBA but just not photos.

Below is what i did

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' Program Excel Messenger
' Purpose : Send Message to Telegram

Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strChatId As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPhoto As String
Dim messageDate As Variant
Dim strPostData As String
Dim strResponse As String

    strChatId ='Group chat ID
    strMessage = Range("A2").Value 'Get value of Cell A2
    strPhoto = "<local image file path>" 'Get value of Cell A3
    messageDate = Now() 'Get current Date and Time
    
        'Detect the value in Cell A1
    If IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        'Send Messsage
        strPostData = "chat_id=" & strChatId & "&text=" & messageDate & vbNewLine & strMessage
        strPostPhoto = "chat_id=" & strChatId & "&photo=" & strPhoto
        
        Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        With objRequest
            .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage?", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .Send (strPostData)
            GetSessionId = .responseText
            MsgBox GetSessionId
        End With
        
        With objRequest
            .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto?", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .Send (strPostPhoto)
            GetSessionId = .responseText
            MsgBox GetSessionId
        End With
        
    End If


End Sub
```

However i get this error when i click on the button to run the above code

**-Bad request wrong HTTP URL specified**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904082/how-to-send-a-desktop-photo-to-telegram-using-excel-vba

Comment: Sorry but there is no direct solution from the post.

Comment: All the comments were just saying about using multipart/form-data but none of it has an example on how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165095/vba-send-file-in-binary-code-to-api-via-post-method/62165922#62165922 shows an example of posting a file

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry but is there a more specific example for telegram bot, because i am new to this language , im not familiar with the APIs

Comment: Sorry too - I'm not a Telegram user and I'm only aware it's possible to post a file from VBA, not sure I've done it myself ever.

Comment: Ahh its alright i guess. Thanks you so much.