# JSON Format for Edits: Calling the Dall E 2 API from VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, multipartform-data, openai-api

Non-coder but still VBA-inclined user here. I’ve been working on VBA code to help me improve my personal workflow within PowerPoint using the OpenAI API. Since I couldn’t find many VBA examples of using the OpenAI API, I’ve been building the JSON strings manually (like an animal). So far it has worked swimmingly and I have a few use cases already up and running. Now I wanted to get to the part about the edits. I want to share an image for edits, and I’m using the below code, but it doesn’t work. I’ll share both the outgoing JSON and the response I get.

`{ "model":"dall-e-2", "image":"image/png;base64,[base64 data here]", "mask":"image/png;base64,[base64 data here]", "prompt":"[prompt text here]", "n":1, "size":"1024x1024" }`

Response:
`{ "error": { "code": null, "message": "'image' is a required property", "param": null, "type": "invalid_request_error" } }`

I’m using POST with the endpoint “/v1/ images / edits”, and “Content-Type” as “multipart/form-data”. Earlier when I was using Content-Type application/json, it gave me an error saying that it expected multipart/form-data. The string I'm using to put together the JSON is as follows:
`data = "{""model"":""dall-e-2"",""image"":""data:image/png;base64," & base64String & """,""n"":1,""size"":""1024x1024""}"`

I would point out that all the prior API calls I've built for OpenAI and DALL-E are working, including text chat, image generation, and the vision API. However, none of those needed the multipart/form-data content type, and I'm afraid I'm completely lost here.

Can one of you guys please help me put this thing together? Highly appreciated! I'm going nuts here! Thanks in advance!

I’m using POST with the endpoint “/v1/ images / edits”, and “Content-Type” as “multipart/form-data”. Earlier when I was using Content-Type application/json, it gave me an error saying that it expected multipart/form-data. The string I'm using to put together the JSON is as follows:
`data = "{""model"":""dall-e-2"",""image"":""data:image/png;base64," & base64String & """,""n"":1,""size"":""1024x1024""}"`

I would point out that all the prior API calls I've built for OpenAI and DALL-E are working, including text chat, image generation, and the vision API. However, none of those needed the multipart/form-data content type, and I'm afraid I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Try https://github.com/bitaller/openai-vba-framework

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165095/vba-send-file-in-binary-code-to-api-via-post-method for an example of making a multi-part POST via VBA

Comment: Thanks a lot @teller However, the OpenAI VBA framework works with text and image generation, which I have been able to accomplish already. In fact, I have also been able to extend this to the VISION API, to interpret images as well. However, with the Vision API, I could pass on the image to the API as base64 string. However, I am struggling with EDIT and VARIATION calls, where the framework above doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, but unfortunately I am not able to translate this into something that works with OpenAI.. :( Any specific support you can provide is highly highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really have time to spend on this, and don't have an account to test with.